# How to translate amino acid sequences to Nucleotide sequences

Tags: proteins, python, phylogenetics, sequence

I want to convert a list of fasta ( protein sequences) in a .text file into corresponding nucleotide sequences. A Google search gives me result of DNA to protein conversion but not vice versa. Also, I came across How do I find the nucleotide sequence of a protein using Biopython?, but this is what I am not looking for. Is there any possible way to do it using python.Moreover, I would like to solve it using python programming. I am sure there must be some way to do it rather than writing a code from scratch. Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/421074/

Answer (score 5):

Although there is not a unique nucleotide sequence that translates to a given protein, one can list all the possible DNA sequences that do translate to that protein.

An online tool that does just that is [Backtranambig](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/st/emboss_backtranambig/), from EMBOSS. It produces a DNA sequence representing all the nucleotide sequences matching the input protein, using [IUPAC ambiguity codes](https://droog.gs.washington.edu/parc/images/iupac.html).

Answer (score 2):

[DNA Chisel](https://edinburgh-genome-foundry.github.io/DnaChisel/index.html) (written in Python) can [reverse translate](https://edinburgh-genome-foundry.github.io/DnaChisel/ref/biotools.html?highlight=reverse_translate#dnachisel.biotools.reverse_translate) a protein sequence:

```py
import dnachisel
from dnachisel.biotools import reverse_translate

record = dnachisel.load_record("seq.fa")
reverse_translate(str(record.seq))
# GGTCATATTTTAAAAATGTTTCCT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because there is redundancy in the genetic code and the *same* protein sequences can be encoded by *different* nucleotide sequences. There are 64 codons and ~20 amino acids, e.g. `GCT`, `GCC`, `GCA` and `GCG` all encode Alanine.

Comment: For the sake of the programming exercise, one could use IUPAC ambiguity codes to reflect the set of possible codons for a given amino-acid.

Comment: @bli Agreed, one could even build a model to predict the underlying codons since there is codon usage bias. For practical purposes I'd do a TBLASTN against NT or similar